# Porting from PLM51 to C

Tags: c, embedded, porting, code-size

I am doing a project where I need to port code from PLM51 to C.

8051 architecture is being used. The microcontroller is romless and an external memory of 64Kb is being used. The PLM51 code size is almost 63Kb.

So my question is that when I port my code from PLM51 to C, will the code size increase or decrease? 
What are the parameters which will decide the increase/decrease in size?

Comment: My first shot at this would be that with a current, optimizing C compiler you may likely see a decrease in size, as the PL/M compiler is probably very old without much optimizations implemented. However something producing 63Kb of binary should be definitely hairy. In a project I had to work on, I had like 3000 lines of PL/M code compiling to about 6Kb, as a part of an overgrown, mostly assembly mess constantly battling with the 64Kb code size limit. So first, can you (or the company) actually afford this? (I mean the time likely spent with porting)

Answer (score 0):

To start out I must say that while I have written in both languages, I have not done a port from PL/M to C or compared the sizes of similar programs written in the two languages.

This question is very difficult to answer with any degree of certainty but the two languages are fairly similar in their level, being fairly low level portable languages.  I seem to remember our rule of thumb for PL/M was an average of around 5 assembler instructions per PL/M statement.  This efficiency will vary between compilers and optimisation levels.

One factor that may have a large impact on the code size of the final image is the external libraries that may be included by the linker.  A particular culprit is the printf formatter that is typically quite large.  In PL/M you would normally write your own character output functions that would be tailored to your specific needs often resulting is smaller code.